# Document count showing zero inspite documents exist in monogdb slave

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongodb cluster with 6 replica set with one master . out of which 3(include master) are in mongodb 3.4 and remaining 3 are 3.6 which i have added as part of upgradation. But for 2 collections Documents replicated to new slave machine (version 3.6) but when i query **document count is zero** . Remaining collections are replicated to slave without any issues . Not sure why document count is displays zero .
[image]

Comment: Can you show your approach?

Comment: Please refer the attachment which i have added .